# Closest Point on a 3 dimensional line to another point

Tags: java, geometry, line, point

I am writing a little library that defines 3D geometry, along with a lot of useful functions for each piece of geometry. I defined a Point3D as having 3 double precision coordinates, one for each axis, and a Line3D as having 2 Point3Ds. In the Line3D class I want a method that would return a point on the line that is closest to the Point passed as an argument.

does anyone know how to do this?

(By The Way I am not looking for distance, but the actual point on the line itself

Answer (score 3):

Let's line is defined by two points P0 and P1, and some point P.
Find normalized direction vector

**d** = (**P1** - **P0**) / Length(**P1** - **P0**)

and vector

**W** = **P** - **P0**

Closest point P(b) at the line is

**Pb** = **d** * ScalarProduct(**W**, **d**)

Not that this method works both for 2D case and for 3D.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the line be `P0P1` and the extra point `Q`.

The parametric equation of the line is

```
P = P0 + t (P1 - P0)
```

The squared distance `PQ²` is

```
(P0 - Q + t (P1 - P0))² = t² (P1 - P0)² + 2 (P1 - P0)(P0 - Q) t + (P0 - Q)²
```

You find the minimum by cancelling the fist derivative wrt `t`:

```
2 t (P1 - P0)² + 2 (P1 - P0)(P0 - Q) = 0
```

This gives you `t`, then `P`.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't taken calc yet, how does this result in the closest point on the line? (and I have to honest... I'm not really sure what stands for either...)

Answer (score 0):

Find the line from that point that is perpendicular to the first line. Then you have two equations in two unknowns, which you can solve for. The solution is the point of intersection. Implement this. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717746/closest-point-on-a-line-to-another-point) for more details.

Comment: well how do you find the line that is perpendicular from that point? I made a similar method for 2 Dimensional lines and had the same idea but it ended up being easier to do something else, however that something else doesn't really translate to 3D stuff very well... got anyother ideas, (or working code for this one)?